# How to split out consequent number?

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I get movie time data from website , but i find that its consequent .

How to split it out and become a json data ?  I can not figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the json data i made:

```
[{"title":["敦克爾克大行動 Dunkirk","女狼嗨到趴 Rough Night","悟空傳 WuKong","猩球崛起 終極決戰 WAR FOR THE PLANET OF THE APES","銀魂 Gintama","蜘蛛人：返校日 Spider-Man: Homecoming","神偷奶爸 3《中文版》  Despicable Me 3 《 CH 》 ","神偷奶爸 3《英文版》  Despicable Me 3《 EN 》"],"time":["09:5011:5513:0014:0015:0016:0518:1019:2020:1522:2000:30\n","10:0011:5013:4015:3017:2020:5022:4000:30\n","10:0013:5516:1020:0522:2000:35\n","10:0012:3513:3515:1016:1017:4518:4520:2021:2022:5500:00\n","10:0017:0023:45\n","10:0012:2514:5017:1519:4021:2022:0500:30\n","10:0011:4519:10\n","12:1518:25\n"],"image":["picture/zip_20170617231635968.jpg","picture/zip_20170528225556605.jpg","picture/zip_20170528231038563.jpg","picture/zip_20170617225530468.jpg","picture/zip_20170617231105860.jpg","picture/zip_20170617224807245.jpg","picture/zip_20170617223724641.jpg","picture/zip_20170617223542725.jpg"]}]
```

I want time becomes like this:
[image]

I use casperjs to get the movie time data:

```
var movieTitle = [];
var movieTime = [];
var movieImage = [];
var allMovie = {};
allMovie.detail = [];

// How to let my movie time split out ?
function getMovieTime() {
    var time = document.querySelectorAll('ul li ul');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(time, function (e) {
        return e.innerText;
    });
}

casper.then(function () {
    movieTitle = this.evaluate(getMovieTitle);
    movieTime = this.evaluate(getMovieTime);
    movieImage = this.evaluate(getMovieImage);
});

casper.then(function () {
    console.log('what is going on');
    this.echo(movieTitle.length + 'Title found :');
    // this.echo(movieTitle.join('\n'));
    this.echo(movieTime.length + 'Time found :');
    //this.echo(movieTime.join('\n'));
    this.echo(movieImage.length + 'Image found :')
    // this.echo(movieImage.join('\n'));

    this.echo(outPutJSON());
});

function outPutJSON() {
    allMovie.detail.push({
        title: movieTitle,
        time: movieTime,
        image: movieImage
    });
    return JSON.stringify(allMovie.detail);
}
```

I have try this:

```
function getMovieTime() {
    var time = document.querySelectorAll('ul li ul');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(time, function (e) {
        return e.innerText.substring(0, 5);
    });
}
```

but i just get each first movie time , its not what i want.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used JavaScript functions like `split`, `substring` and `join` within a loop to get the desired result.

```js
var data = [
   {
      "title":[
         "敦克爾克大行動 Dunkirk",
         "女狼嗨到趴 Rough Night",
         "悟空傳 WuKong",
         "猩球崛起 終極決戰 WAR FOR THE PLANET OF THE APES",
         "銀魂 Gintama",
         "蜘蛛人：返校日 Spider-Man: Homecoming",
         "神偷奶爸 3《中文版》  Despicable Me 3 《 CH 》 ",
         "神偷奶爸 3《英文版》  Despicable Me 3《 EN 》"
      ],
      "time":[
         "09:5011:5513:0014:0015:0016:0518:1019:2020:1522:2000:30\n",
         "10:0011:5013:4015:3017:2020:5022:4000:30\n",
         "10:0013:5516:1020:0522:2000:35\n",
         "10:0012:3513:3515:1016:1017:4518:4520:2021:2022:5500:00\n",
         "10:0017:0023:45\n",
         "10:0012:2514:5017:1519:4021:2022:0500:30\n",
         "10:0011:4519:10\n",
         "12:1518:25\n"
      ],
      "image":[
         "picture/zip_20170617231635968.jpg",
         "picture/zip_20170528225556605.jpg",
         "picture/zip_20170528231038563.jpg",
         "picture/zip_20170617225530468.jpg",
         "picture/zip_20170617231105860.jpg",
         "picture/zip_20170617224807245.jpg",
         "picture/zip_20170617223724641.jpg",
         "picture/zip_20170617223542725.jpg"
      ]
   }
];

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
 var movie = data[i];
 movie.time = getProperTime(movie.time);
}

console.log(movie.time[0]);

function getProperTime(time){
  for(var i=0;i<time.length; i++){
    time[i] = time[i].split('\n')[0].split(":");
    for(var j=1; j<time[i].length-1; j++){
      time[i][j] = time[i][j].substring(0, 2) + "," + time[i][j].substring(2);
    }
    time[i] = time[i].join(":").split(",");
  }
  return time;
}
```

Comment: Is this answer fine for you? From what i understood you get the data in json but the time is in continues string, so i wrote the function to split time string as required.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i try the `substring` that update on my question , it get first movie time , not what i want .

Your answer is a little complicated for me , i try it.

I declare `var data = outPutJSON();` and copy your code , it looks like i do not declare time , where is time should i declare it ?

Comment: The error shows `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'time.length') ` . I can figure it out if i can understand what is your movie.time.

Comment: I only used the JSON you have it in your question. It has `time` as a key.

Comment: I think you should let your code remain as it is, get the JSON data as you are getting it right now. After you get the JSON run it though function i have in my answer and you'll get the time in desired format.

Comment: Yep my mistake , i create another file and copy it , i shows the time that has been split out.  But i use `console.log(time);` i just see the first movie time , can i print the others movie time ?

Comment: Run it though the loop for all movies i suppose.

Comment: OK , i will try it . Thanks you very much.